# React "ReferenceError: indexedDB is not defined" yet it somehow works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image: Basicly the entire problem in one picture]

I installed idb-keyval via yarn

I imported it by using

```
import { set } from 'idb-keyval';
```

and set a variable by using

```
set('hello', 'world');
```

As the picture shows it works. Sort of. The entry goes into the indexedDB, yet it tells me that indexedDB is not defined.

And yes, I already restarted the dev server.

Comment: May be storing it in any variable might work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you code `set` in `useEffect`.
that works for my case...
I added my test code below.

```
    import { set, get } from 'idb-keyval';
    import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

    export default function Main() {

        const [member, setMember] = useState([]);
        const [member2, setMember2] = useState([]);


        useEffect(() => {

            set('member', {
                "spec": [
                    { name: 'bar', age: 20 },
                    { name: 'dall', age: 32 },
                    { name: 'hong', age: 47 },
                ],
                "spec2": [
                    { name: 'bar2', age: 20 },
                    { name: 'dall2', age: 32 },
                    { name: 'hong2', age: 47 },
                ],
            }).then(() => {
                get('member').then(user => { 
                    setMember(user.spec) 
                    setMember2(user.spec2) 
                });

            });
        }, []);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>IdbTest</h1>
                {member.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index}>
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                        <p>{item.age}</p>
                    </div>
                })}
                {member2.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index}>
                        <p>{item.name}</p>
                        <p>{item.age}</p>
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```